# Coefficient Estimators of $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ Weighted Least Squares Linear Regression

Tags: linear-regression

I have a feeling there should be a mathematical formular for determining the estimators of the coefficients of a  $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ Weighted Linear Regression.

I was able to derive the estimators ($a$ and $b$) for the non-weighted linear regression ($y=ax+b$). I did it by minimizing $\sum \epsilon^2 $ where $\epsilon = y - (ax+b) $

I partially differentiated $\sum \epsilon^2 $ wrt $a$ and $b$ and equating it to zero. at the end i got the estimators as:

$$a = \frac{n\sum xy - \sum x \sum y}{n\sum {x}^2 - {(\sum x)}^2} $$

and

$$b = \frac{\sum y - a\sum x}{n} $$

Now my question is this:

If I decide to use a  $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ weight on the linear regression $y=ax+b$, is there a way to minimize the least squares of the weighted error (ie minimize $\sum \frac{1}{x^{2}} \ [y - (ax+b)]^2 $ ) and come up with a simple mathematical relationship to determine the estimators $a$ and $b$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I decide to use a  $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ weight on the linear regression $y=ax+b$, is there a way to minimize the least squares of the weighted error (i.e. minimize $\sum \frac{1}{x^{2}} \ [y - (ax+b)]^2 $ ) and come up with a simple mathematical relationship to determine the estimators $a$ and $b$ ?

Why not? You have two equations in two variables. Just solve them.

We have to minimize $S=\sum \frac 1{x_i^2}[y_i-(ax_i+b)]^2=\sum \left[\frac {y_i}{x_i}-\left(a+\frac {b}{x_i}\right)\right]^2$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial S}{\partial a}&=0\Rightarrow\sum \left[\frac {y_i}{x_i}-\left(a+\frac {b}{x_i}\right)\right]=0\Rightarrow \boxed{a=\frac{\sum\frac {y_i}{x_i}-b\sum\frac {1}{x_i}}{n}}\tag{1}\\
\frac{\partial S}{\partial b}&=0\Rightarrow\sum \frac1{x_i}\left[\frac {y_i}{x_i}-\left(a+\frac {b}{x_i}\right)\right]=0\Rightarrow a\sum\frac1{x_i}+b\sum\frac1{x_i^2}=\sum\frac {y_i}{x_i^2}\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}
Putting the value of $a$ from $(1)$ in $(2)$, we get
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\sum\frac {y_i}{x_i}-b\sum\frac {1}{x_i}}{n}\right)\sum\frac1{x_i}+b\sum\frac1{x_i^2}&=\sum\frac {y_i}{x_i^2}\\
\sum\frac {y_i}{x_i}\sum\frac1{x_i}-b\left(\sum\frac {1}{x_i}\right)^2+nb\sum\frac1{x_i^2}&=n\sum\frac {y_i}{x_i^2}\\
\boxed{b=\frac{n\sum\frac {y_i}{x_i^2}-\sum\frac {y_i}{x_i}\sum\frac1{x_i}}{n\sum\frac1{x_i^2}-\left(\sum\frac {1}{x_i}\right)^2}}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks @sameer, I had actually followed the step you posted but wasn't sure I was right. I guess I got confused on why $\sum \frac{1}{x} [y - (ax+b)]=0$ and not $\sum [y - (ax+b)]=0$. But now I realise that I'm dealing with a weighted linear regression. Got similar answer as you, however I noticed a slight error in your equation (2). I think you meant to write $\sum \frac{1}{x} [ \frac{y}{x} - (a+ \frac{b}{x})]=0$. Thanks so much once again.

Comment: @Obinoscopy I get why I was apprehensive of some dimensional inconsistencies earlier. Thanks! I hope it is correct now.